# cloud storage 503 error after setting a coldline rule on a huge bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We add a rule on a huge  GCS bucket ( 39T) to set to coldline storage objects than was not updated from 90 days. I imagine that a lot of objects were concerned by the rule immedialtely ( maybe 90 %).
Since the rule was set on, we observe a huge instability on the jobs trying to write objects into that bucket. Most of them ( maybe all ) were getting a 503 backend error.

I don't see any concerns of that type in the Object Lifecycle Managemen, which should have alerted us on not doing such an operation.

Does someone already faced an issue of than type with GCS ?
I suspect the bucket "too busy" on doing the storage change and not available for other jobs.

When we deleted the rule, the bucket get available back from writing.
Does someone has a workaround to change storage class with avoiding unavailability ?

Comment: Hi, I have a question for you. have you tried only to change the storage class of have you tried to delete some of the objects in your bucket?

Comment: Hi, no there was no attempts to delete objects in bucket as far as i know. Only  a rule was added to set to coldline 90 days age objects

Comment: If you are not trying to delete objects, you should take into consideration some other things, like do your [objects have a naming convention that distributes load evenly cross key ranges](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention)? If  not, this could be the reason why of the issue.